# Reflectively look up enum value by String in Swift 2

Tags: swift, enums, swift2

I'm writing an XML-based descriptor for UIKit and am wondering if there's any slim possibility at all of taking a string like "UIStackViewAlignmentCenter" or "UIStackViewAlignment.Center" and converting it into the appropriate constant value.

I'm really expecting this is impossible, but wanted to ask just in case.

My fallback plan is to create a helper class that allows me to register strings like "UIStackViewAlignmentCenter" and map them to values, but this is going to be painstaking adding all of the possible constants. :(

Comment: Why not just store them as keys in a dictionary or as enums?

Comment: It's not the storing that's the problem, it's getting them all in there. 

Comment: Store the key-value pairs in an XML document, read them in and load them into a dictionary? Reflection like this is really not an option in Swift, even if it's possible it's not recommended.